# strange output after appending a column

Tags: cbind

I `cbind` a column "class" to a data frame and got a new `tdm1`, `tdm1<- cbind(tdm1, class)`, it's all good

the content of class looks like this

```
1     715
2     715    
3     707    
4     705    
5     704    
6     701    
7     701    
...
```

Then after `cbind`, I want to get a look at the class column by using `tdm1[,ncol(tdm1)]`, somehow i got `35 Levels: 156 174 205 250 295 324 335 340 343 345 348 349 361 370 375 381 382 428 439 451 455 701 704 705 706 ... 72` after the correct values for the entire column. it's like a summary of the column value. Idon't know where it came from. this additional information makes my later knn classification weird. how do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your object is a factor. Calling `?factor` reveals:

```
factor returns an object of class "factor" which has a set of integer
codes the length of x with a "levels" attribute of mode character and  
unique (!anyDuplicated(.))
```

The `levels` attribute being printed to your dismay reflects all the unique values contained within the object you are printing. To get rid of it, try:

```
as.numeric(as.characer(tdm1[,ncol(tdm1)]))
```